# Product name in breadcrumb even if duplicate?

Tags: seo, breadcrumbs

I have a breadcrumb like this:

```
Clothes > Shoes > Paciotti > Cesare
```

**Cesare** is the name of the product, which is also present as a title. Wouldn't it be better to remove the product name from the breadcrumb SEO-wise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a problem SEO wise and is [encouraged by Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/185417?hl=en) as it aids the user experience.

> A breadcrumb trail is a set of links (breadcrumbs) that can help a
>   user understand and navigate your site's hierarchy

Perhaps you are getting a bit too strung up on thinking about duplicating content. When talking about duplicate content in most cases its referring to whole sentences and paragraphs of the same content, like if you had 40 products all with the same descriptions.

Using the same words within a title, URL, breadcrumb links, h1 heading and body content on a page is not duplicating content, this will naturally happen as the page is on a particular subject.